# Custom number format with unit in EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

Is it possible to set the format for a cell/column in excel like shown in the image using EPPlus?
What's the proper syntax to achieve that? The following code doesn't work.

```
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Numberformat.Format = @"@"" Mhz""";
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the value to `string`

```
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Numberformat.Format = @"@"" Mhz""";
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value = "10.5";
```